# Why did my labels move?

Tags: qgis

I did a bunch of "housekeeping" recently—deleting old unneeded attribute fields, renaming other fields, etc.. Now I find that all of the labels that I had previously manually repositioned  seem to have shifted down a small amount (by an amount approximately equal to the size of the label letters). Any idea what might have caused this, and how I can correct it (other than by manually readjusting all of them (hundreds))? And more importantly, so I can avoid causing this to happen again? (Using QGIS 3.4)

Comment: Hm. Not sure why that happened, but you could use the Field Calculator to adjust the label position fields. Are they actual attribute table fields, or auxiliary storage?

Comment: The first time you move a label, QGIS asks you to "choose a primary key to use for joining with internal data storage." Then you have to choose a unique ID field from a dropdown menu. If you changed the primary key field in some way, that would affect the auxiliary storage. If it only shifted your labels a little bit it seems like you got off easily. I would expect the labels to be completely scrambled.

Comment: @TVZ, Your questions have the characteristic of not providing enough information to reproduce the behavior that you adduce and for which you request an answer. Please, include detailed information on the procedures used, so that a user who wants to help you find a solution can at least reproduce the problem.